# How to show Modal Image with Javascript - But also have a pseudo Overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, modal-dialog

I would like to show a modal/popup image when I click on an image in my gallery. I took the example from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp which is easy enough to implement.
However, because I would like another overlay effect (image goes dark-transparent and shows a text overlay when hovering), I have to wrap my modal-trigger in a div.

I placed the `id="myImg"` into the div so I can at least trigger the modal. It was supposed to be in the img-tag like so: `<img id="myImg" src="images/kayla-good-qual.jpg" alt="Test Image Modal" style="width: 100%">`. This wouldn't trigger the modal at all, unless I would remove the `class="img-container"`.

For my solution above, I assume the javascript can't find the image src and alt? I am a noob in Javascript and I couldn't figure out how to amend the code - if that's the mistake.

So, what to do so I can keep my image and text overlay/hover and at the same time have the image modal working?

Below my JS, CSS and HTML code.

Thanks heaps!

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-container:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 0 0 8px; 
  position:absolute;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  top:0; left:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.img-container:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
}

/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
/*#myImg {
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
   opacity: 0.7;
}*/

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
   display: none; /* Hidden by default */
   position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
   z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
   padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%; /* Full width */
   height: 100%; /* Full height */
   overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
   background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   width: 80%;
   max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   width: 80%;
   max-width: 700px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #ccc;
   padding: 10px 0;
   height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
   animation-name: zoom;
   animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
   from {transform:scale(0)}
   to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;
   right: 35px;
   color: #f1f1f1;
   font-size: 40px;
   font-weight: bold;
   transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
   color: #bbb;
   text-decoration: none;
   cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
   @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
      .modal-content {
         width: 100%;
      }
}
```

```html
<div id="myImg" data-content="Text added on hover" class="img-container">
   <img src="images/kayla-good-qual.jpg" alt="Test Image Modal" style="width: 100%">
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <span class="close">&times;</span>
   <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
   <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my own problem, althoug it might be quite bad code:

- I added an id to my img-tag: `id="myImgSrc"` so it looks like this: `<img id="myImgSrc" src="images/kayla-good-qual.jpg" alt="Test Image Modal" style="width: 100%">`
- In my Javascript I changed both `this` to `document.getElementById("myImgSrc")`

If anyone knows a cleaner solution, I am all ears (and eyes)!